EF Core: How can I use string data type in foreign key relationship?
I created a Language database table consisting of a single column:
CREATE TABLE Languages
( 
    CultureId CHAR(2) PRIMARY KEY
)

I'd like to use this column in other tables as foreign key column:
CREATE TABLE Texts
( 
    TextOd NVARCHAR(30),
    CultureId CHAR(2) 
         FOREIGN KEY FK_Texts_CultureId REFERENCES Languages (CultureId),
    --
    CONSTRAINT Texts_PK PRIMARY KEY (Text, CultureId),

    TextContent NVARCHAR(3000) NOT NULL
)

Entity Framework Core doesn't seem to provide for string foreign key relationships out of the box.
Is there a convention/attribute/FluentAPI to make this work?
Here's an MRE: https://github.com/SetTrend/EFC-SQLite-MRE

Please [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others to provide an answer faster.
Add your code to the question itself, not on an external site. Also add the full complete error messages you get, when you try to run your code.

I think you already asked the same question in another (currently deleted) post. EFC supports all primitive type FKs, your problem is that you are trying to use navigation property in the PK.

You have a Text column in your PK definition: CONSTRAINT Texts_PK PRIMARY KEY (Text, CultureId), - but your table (as far as you've shown it) doesn't have a Text column anywhere ....

The code should be part of the question. Not behind a link (that doesn't contain runnable code either, by the way).

EF does work with strings as PKs/FKs but by default it will be expecting NVarchar or comparable. To use a CHAR(2) then specify[Column("CultureId", TypeName = "CHAR(2)"] or .HasColumnType("CHAR(2)") in the modelBuilding should do the trick.

For those of you who are asking for an MRE here: Has anyone of you EVER seen all complex code with explanation that's necessary to reproduce the issue fully here? I created a FULL MRE and linked to it. What do you expect? Are you to indolent to follow a plain hyperlink? And, BTW, the code is compilable and the test function runs, but fails. That's the issue!

@IvanStoev, so, what would you suggest to make this run?
